# HTML5 Audio Auto Play IE Doesn't Play

Tags: jquery, html5-audio

I have a bit of code to play audio tag HTML5 when clicked. Works properly in all browsers. I recently tried to convert it to automatically play when the page opens (no click required). Works fine in Chrome and FF, but won't play in IE... although I don't see an obvious error.

```
// add a 'self play' function on a wrapper div
jQuery('.autoplay').each( function(i) {
            if( jQuery(this).attr("rel") ) {   
                var xv = jQuery(this);
                x = jQuery(this).attr('rel') + ext;                                             
                audioElements.push( document.createElement('audio') ); 
                //alert(audioElements.length);
                //alert(xv);
                // alert(x);
                y = audioElements.length-1;
                audioElements[y].setAttribute('src', x);
                audioElements[y].load();
                audioElements[y].addEventListener("canplay", function(){ xv.addClass('canplay');    });             
                // audioElements[y].currentTime=0;                       
                audioElements[y].play();
                // alert(x);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

The live site is http://jchmusic.com. But again, if you go to http://jchmusic.com/songs-from-detroit and click on any icon, the same basic code works fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not the best at jQuery so I'll leave a fix / workaround to someone capable of giving you an accurate and correct answer. What I can tell you is that the audio tag was new to HTML5 and is not supported in IE8 and earlier. See http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_audio_autoplay.asp for more information.

Comment: Tnanks for the suggestions. As I said, the code works -fine- if attached to an <a> click function. I'm using IE9.

Answer (score 0):

Try including this

```
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
```

This javascript informs IE about the new HTML5 elements

Comment: I'll give it a shot, but since the code works when used as a click function, I wonder if this is necessary. I've done some basic tests that the audio object is loading without error.

Answer (score 0):

Crap... wasted a lot of time thinking this was a code issue. It's apparently a problem with the MP3, which I don't get, but that's another story. The MP3 plays fine locally.

The reason I didn't catch it is that I have MP3, OGG and WAV versions of each song so apparently other browsers were falling back to the alternate file type... but IE can't.

If I had simply tested the MP3 I woulda saved myself the trouble.

Anyhoo... I re-rendered the MP3 and the new version works fine in IE.

Moral: Ockham's Razor.